# If $km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$, must $\sqrt{k}$ be a squarefree palindrome?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, palindrome

Let $$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \mid x}{d}$$ denote the *sum of divisors* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers or positive integers.

Recall that a *Descartes number* is an odd number $n = km$, with $1 < k$, $1 < m$, satisfying $$\sigma(k)(m+1)=2km.$$  ($m$ is called the quasi-Euler prime of $n$.)  Note that we define $\sigma(m) := m + 1$ even when $m$ is composite (that is, we *pretend* that $m$ is prime).

Notice that the lone Descartes number that is known is
$$\mathscr{D} = k'm' = {{3003}^2}\cdot{22021}.$$

In particular, note that:

- $k$ is a square.
- $\sigma(k)/m = 2k - \sigma(k)$
- $m \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Note that, for the lone Descartes number $\mathscr{D}$ that we know,
$$\sqrt{k'} = 3003,$$
which happens to be a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number).

Furthermore, since
$$\sqrt{k'} = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot {11} \cdot {13},$$
then $\sqrt{k'}$ is [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).

Here is my inquiry:

> **QUESTION:** Given an *arbitrary* Descartes number $n = km > 1$ with quasi-Euler prime $m$, must it necessarily be the case that $\sqrt{k}$ is a squarefree palindrome?

**Alas, this is where I get stuck, as we currently do not have another example of a Descartes number.**

Comment: Note that, per [Banks, et. al](https://home.uncg.edu/~f_saidak/dn.pdf)'s paper on Descartes numbers, the condition that $\sqrt{k}$ is squarefree follows from assuming that $n$ is cube-free.

Comment: Babylonians wouldn't see it as a palindrome *(base 60 instead of 10)*, probably just a coincidence.

Comment: @Vepir:  I think you missed the point.  A number being a palindrome is **base-dependent**.  (It is implicit in my post that I am operating in base $10$.)

Comment: Yes, my point was that base-dependent things tend to be coincidences.